# Does electron have some intrinsic ~$10^{21}$ Hz oscillations (de Broglie's clock/Zitterbewegung)?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, time, oscillators, dirac-equation

Louis De Broglie has postulated in 1924 that with electron's mass there comes some $\approx 10^{21}$Hz [inner oscillation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matter_wave_clock): $E=mc^2=h f=\hbar \omega$.

We would get such oscillation e.g. if using $E=mc^2$ energy in stationary solution of Schrödinger's equation: $\psi=\psi_0 e^{iEt/\hbar}$.

Somehow similar (?) oscillations come out of solution of [Dirac equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_equation) - called [Zitterbewegung](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zitterbewegung) ("trembling motion").

Regarding their **experimental status**, I have found 2008 Foundation of Physics paper: [A Search for the de Broglie Particle Internal Clock by Means of Electron Channeling](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10701-008-9225-1). Thanks to using ~80MeV electrons, time dilation leads to ~0.4nm  distance between "ticks" of such clock, which agrees with lattice constant of silicon crystal they shoot at. While tuning the angle, they observe narrow absorption maximum when distances agree - intuitively, **the electron's clock  finds resonance with periodic structure of the crystal**. [Here is Hestenes](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/f478/e1334656d27e76ecaabf465574ef8e593635.pdf) paper about this experiment.

There are a few more papers claiming **experimental observation of Zitterbewegung** (e.g. [[1]](https://www.nature.com/articles/nature08688), [[2]](https://journals.aps.org/pra/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevA.88.021604), [[3]](http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1367-2630/15/7/073011/meta)), but they are for physical simulation of Dirac equation - not exactly of electron.

**Can we say that electron has some intrinsic ~$10^{21}$Hz oscillations, or maybe there is still some problem/doubts regarding such claim?**
Does it also concern other particles? Molecules? Larger objects? It seems problematic as its frequency is proportional to mass.

How such oscillation is realized? Do e.g. [breathers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breather) (oscillating solitons) bring a proper intuition?
Can such oscillations be imagined as the source of coupled "pilot" waves in dBB interpretation?

Answer (score -3):

Yes, there are experimental and theoretical works proving that the electron is a spherical standing wave without dispersion.
Relevant references can be found in the recommended literature for the article.
http://vixra.org/abs/1710.0239

Comment: Any peer reviewed articles?

Comment: http://science.sciencemag.org/content/early/2013/01/09/science.1230767

Comment: The Science article does not seem to support the statement of your answer. It does not seem to have anything to do with the Compton frequency of the electron, it is about the Compton frequency of the Cs atom.  However, the Cs atom contains a lot of protons and neutrons, and if we assume that each proton and neutron has some intrinsic frequency, then the Cs atom, being a composite particle, does not have such intrinsic frequency.

Comment: But this article exposes the hypothesis of de Broglie  $\hbar\omega  =mc^{2}$. For an electron there are many such experimental studies and articles.

Comment: I explained why this article does not really support the idea of intrinsic frequency for Cs atom. As for electrons, you should quote a peer- reviewed article supporting your answer. A vixra article? Really?

Comment: There are articles in Vixra and in the Arxiv  https://arxiv.org/abs/1403.4580v2  https://arxiv.org/abs/0802.3227v1. Why are they not satisfied? And this publication is not peer-reviewed   https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10701-008-9225-1 ? I dont know.

Comment: The arxiv articles are still not peer-reviewed. The article in Foundations of physics is indeed peer-reviewed, but there is nothing there supporting your statement "the electron is a spherical standing wave". Moreover, the Foundations article is somewhat strange: it looks like the experiment was performed in the eighties, but the article was only published thirty years later. Furthermore, the article demonstrates some resonance revealed in a "periodic" field of a row of atoms, rather than  an internal frequency. Anyway, I don't see a proof of internal frequency so far.